# Create a shell that can start 3 separate web services at once

Tags: web-services, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a .sh that will start 3 separate web services in order.

Example:

```
cd to User/me/Scripts/web
./webservice-start
cd to User/me/Scripts/db-services
./db1-start
./db2-start
```

This is the idea, the problem being that bash waits for the process to see a done statement. These services do not finish, therefore it never gets the queue to move on.

I know the syntax is static, it's just for me. I'm more looking for the methodology.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to run each of the three scripts in the background:

```
cd to User/me/Scripts/web
./webservice-start &
cd to User/me/Scripts/db-services
./db1-start &
./db2-start &
```

The `&` command terminator runs the command in the background, allowing the shell to move on to the next command.